# How to have infinity slope in the output without the zerodivisionerror?

Tags: python, gradient, infinity

> so the question is asking me to implement a function to calculate the distance and the slope between two points. If the slope is a valid value. Print (the slope is XX and the distance is XX) but if it is a vertical line then print (the slope is infinity and the distance is XX).

Here is my code:

```
import math
def points(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    slope=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
    distance=math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)
    if (x2-x1)==0:
        print('The slope is infinity '+' and the distance is '+str(slope))

    else:
        print('The slope is '+str(slope)+' and the distance is '+str(distance))
```

> the code work just fine until it comes to a vertical line where x1==x2, then it will not be working and show zero division error

Answer (score 0):

> I have figured out the way to do it so I will answer my question(I hope it is okay to do so).

```
import math
def points(x1,y1,x2,y2):
    distance=math.sqrt((x2-x1)**2+(y2-y1)**2)
    if x1==x2:
        slope='infinity'
        print('The slope is '+slope+' and the distance is '+str(distance))

    else:
        slope=(y2-y1)/(x2-x1)
        print('The slope is '+str(slope)+' and the distance is '+str(distance))
```